# If there is a finite-closed topology on $X$ with 3 clopen elements, then $X$ is finite

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $T$ be a finite-closed topology on $X$. $X$ has 3 clopen elements. Prove that $X$ is finite.

Empty set must be one of these clopen sets as well as $X$. Therefore, we are left with some element $S$ which does not equal $X$ or empty set. $S$ is open in $X$ and therefore $X\setminus S$ is closed. It then says that $S \cup X\setminus S = X$, and therefore $X$ is finite because $S$ and $X\setminus S$ are finite. However, isn't $X\setminus S$'s being finite dependent on $X$ being finite. What am I missing.

Comment: You are right. ${}{}$

Comment: @John Hmm... That troubles me. I'll add more information. Perhaps I'm not understanding something.

Comment: can you add more information about the problem I don't completely understand ?

Comment: maybe if you could post the full proof or screen shoot or something.

Comment: You better provide which books are you using, what is being proved....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the finite-closed topology says that the closed sets are exactly the finite sets (and the whole space). So since $X\setminus S$ is closed, it has to be finite.